# What does this bcf error mean?

Tags: linux, output, error-handling, filter, file-format

I ran this code to filter out biallelic variants from my vcf file:

```
bcftools view --max-alleles 2 --exclude-types indels merged.ecDNA.vcf.gz>merged.ecDNA2.vcf.gz
```

However, I got an error message:

```
[E::vcf_parse_format] Number of columns at 1:219048632 does not match the number of samples (111 vs 231)
Error: VCF parse error
```

The thing is, `merged.ecDNA2.vcf.gz` still appeared in my directory and it seems to be a working vcf file. So I was wondering, if my code actually produced a vcf file that appears to be normally functioning, would the above error still have any effect on my output file?

What should the number `1:219048632` refer to?

I tried this code too:

```
bcftools view -m2 -M2 -v snps merged.ecDNA.vcf.gz>merged.ecDNA3.vcf.gz
```

And I got the same error message for the above code.

If anyone could give a general explanation of what that error message means, it would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for different reasons but the general cause is that somewhere in the process of creating your VCF file, the file got corrupted. If for example, you start with a .txt file may be the case that in some lines, you have more columns than in the others.

For example, once I got a file that didn't start a new line after a supposed line end. This doubled the number of columns, and I got a similar error.

What I would do in those cases is to check that specific position.

```
bcftools view -H merged.ecDNA2.vcf.gz | grep 219048632 -A 3 -B 3
```

by searching 219048632 you will find the line that is corrupted and it will print 3 lines Before and After so you can see what is the actual problem.